# Flag declined but comment deleted nevertheless

Tags: support, flagging

I raised a “not an answer” flag on a question that was declined with “flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer”.

[image]

However, the respective answer was deleted afterwards nevertheless, action that seems to be contradicting the flag’s declination justification.

[image]

Is this a bug or the result of two different actions by two different moderators? And if it’s the latter, how should this situations be handled/avoided?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The timeline was as follows:

1. You flagged the post.
2. I saw the flag and decided that the answer was just wrong rather than being not an answer.
3. Someone else flagged the post.
4. Another moderator saw that flag and decided that it was valid.

These things happen. You are always going to get cases where different moderators take different decisions. We do discuss things when we're really not sure what the correct course of action to take is, but I didn't this time as I thought it was clear.

In retrospect I can see that perhaps I should have come down on the other side of that decision, but we all make mistakes from time to time.

Comment: No sweat, I was just curious how things work in situations like this. Thanks!